# The function " std:: variant <_Types...> operator =" cannot be referenced, since this function has been removed

Tags: c++, c++17

Error text in the setWord method.

I can't set one std::variant to another. The compiler writes that the assignment operation was deleted, but it is not.

The approximate text of the error: "*The function " std::variant <_Types...> operator =" cannot be referenced, since this function has been removed*"

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct longCommand  
{
    uint8_t     cop;
    uint8_t     r1 : 4;
    uint8_t     r2 : 4;
    uint16_t    addres;         //Адрес для перехода
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)       
struct shortCommand
{
    uint8_t     cop;
    uint8_t     r1 : 4;
    uint8_t     r2 : 4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct doubleShortCommand
{
    shortCommand firstCMD;
    shortCommand secondCMD;
};

typedef std::variant<shortCommand, longCommand, doubleShortCommand> typesOfCommands;
typedef std::variant<int, unsigned int, float> typesOfData;
typedef std::variant<typesOfCommands, typesOfData> WORD;

class Memory
{
private:
    std::vector<WORD> _memory 
        = decltype(_memory)(0xFFFF);
public:
    Memory() {};
    ~Memory() { _memory.clear(); }

    WORD getWord(IP _ip)noexcept;

    void setWord(IP _ip,
        WORD w)noexcept;
};

void Memory::setWord(IP _ip, WORD w) noexcept
{
    _memory[_ip] = w;
                ^^^  The function " std:: variant <_Types...> operator =" cannot be referenced, since this function has been removed
}
```

I tested these actions on an empty project, everything worked fine. I don't know what the problem is.

```
#include <variant>

int main()
{
std::variant<int, float> w{12};
std::variant<int, float> c;
c = w;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What the problem you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

[variant.assign](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#assign-5) says:

> This operator is defined as deleted unless all the elements are both copy constructible and copy assignable.

You haven't posted a complete program to try (specifically, I don't know what `shortCommand`, `longCommand` and `doubleShortCommand` are), but that's where I'd look.  Are those types both copy constructible and copy assignable?

(Later) this code compiles for me (using clang):

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct longCommand  
{
    uint8_t     cop;
    uint8_t     r1 : 4;
    uint8_t     r2 : 4;
    uint16_t    addres;         //Адрес для перехода
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)       
struct shortCommand
{
    uint8_t     cop;
    uint8_t     r1 : 4;
    uint8_t     r2 : 4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct doubleShortCommand
{
    shortCommand firstCMD;
    shortCommand secondCMD;
};

typedef std::variant<shortCommand, longCommand, doubleShortCommand> typesOfCommands;
typedef std::variant<int, unsigned int, float> typesOfData;
typedef std::variant<typesOfCommands, typesOfData> WORD;

static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<typesOfCommands>, "typesOfCommands");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<typesOfData>,     "typesOfData");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<typesOfCommands>, "typesOfCommands");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<typesOfData>,     "typesOfData");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<WORD>,     "WORD");

void setW(WORD &w, const WORD val) { w = val; }
```

Comment: These are all structures. I edited the post. @MarshalClow